# Does React Hot Loader preserve 'this'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, es6-class, arrow-functions

As far as I could check the code, hot loader creates a new component and replaces the component in the DOM with the new component. The state is passed from the old component to the new one.

How does this work with the `this` that was pointing to the old component?

**EDIT**. Adding more info.

**Example 1**: Say that in the constructor i stored a result of a computation (which isn't rendered so it doesn't need to go into `state`).

```
this.myResult = doSomeCalculation();
```

If React hot loader is recreating the component then it should call the constructor and redo the variable. However, if that line of code was called in a callback then if the object is recreated then that variable would no longer be available to access it through `this`. Correct?

**Example 2**: `this` was passed to a function outside of the component so that the function can call `this.setState` in case it needs to update the state of the component. If the React hot loader is recreating the component then the old `this` is no longer valid and if that function tries to call `this.setState` using that old `this` the state of the new component won't change. Correct?

**Note**: These are anti-patterns which shouldn't be used in real code. They are here just for illustration purposes to better explain the nature of the question.

Comment: `this` would refer to a particular instance. If they're replacing that instance, then `this` will not point to the same object.

Comment: Yeah, that's seems reasonable, but it's hard to imagine anything working correctly once the class has been replaced and 'this' not updated. But yet hot reloading somehow works...

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean by `this` being updated. Are you referring to other objects referring to the reloaded component?

Comment: React works based on state. Just replicating the state will/should give the same output no matter how many times you reproduce it. If you do anything outside of the state, that would be lost with hot reloading.

Comment: @BrahmaDev I know how React hot loading works with the state. My question is how it works with 'this'. If your answer is that it doesn't preserve 'this' then that's fine but in that case please make sure that's a correct answer and put it as an answer, not comment.